# Duvida com relacionamento de tabelas - Modelagem

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, mysql, cardinalidade

Seguinte galera, to com 3 tabelas aqui, que estou na duvida como relacionar elas.
Estou estudando relacionamento de tabelas aqui... Esse projeto é um sistema de estoque, e não tem intenção nenhuma, a não ser praticar e estudar!
Minha duvida é a seguinte, eu tenho a tabela **roles** (funções), a tabela **categories** (categorias) e a tabela **permissions** (permissões), eu quero dizer q cada role vai ter permissão de **ler**, **editar** e **apagar** cada registro de **category**.
Que tipo de relacionamento seria nesse caso?
Muitos Para Muitos ? Usaria a tabela **permissions** como tabela **pivot**?
Agradeço desde já quem poder contribuir com alguma explicação, esse negocio de modelagem ta me deixando louco..
[image: Relacionamento]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que entre a tabela **roles** e a tabela **categories** há um relacionamento de muitos para muitos, ou seja uma função poderá alterar varias categorias e uma categoria poderá ser alterada por varias funções, claro que isso irá depender das regras de negócio da aplicação. Esse cenário que citei gera a necessidade de uma tabela intermediária entre essas outras duas. Nessa tabela deverá conter a chave estrangeira de **roles** e de **categories**, assim com você fez nas imagens.

Caso suas regras de negócio permitam que apenas uma função possa ler, editar ou apagar uma ou mais categorias nós teria-mos um relacionamento de um para muitos, nesse caso não seria necessário a tabela de **permissions**. Já que você poderia guardar a chave estrangeira dessa **roles** dentro da tabela **categories**.

Comment: é isso mesmo que estou pretendendo fazer, uma função poderá alterar varias categorias, e uma categoria poderá ser alterada por varias funções. 
ai tinha criado a tabela permissions pra ela ser a tabela pivot.
Vlw pela explicação, estou estudando sobre fico muito confuso.. só queria ouvir uma segunda opinião.. muito obrigado!